# Write on bootstrap top panel line?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to achieve a look using bootstrap like this:

[image]

If you see the lines that say Top Hit, Artists and Genres I was hoping that I could put it on the top line of a panel like this:

[image]

I would like to put the text like "Top Hit" on the top of the panel.

Thanks, couldn't figure this out and hope you guys might know :-)

Comment: I believe you need to use a workaround, positioning a DIV onto the border itself. `position:absolute;` and `left:_px;top:_px;` or with `margin-top:-10px;` for example. Don't forget to make the background colour of the text the same as behind the border as not to have a strike-through effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to make use of negative margin to achieve this.

Say you have the HTML as:

```
<div>

    <h1>Artists</h1>

</div>
```

Then you need CSS as:

```
div{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border:2px solid black;
    margin-top:10px;
    text-align: center;
}

h1{
    width:50px;
    margin-top:-10px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background:white;
}
```

Explanation:
Inside the `div`, align the text in the center. Give **negative value** of `margin-top` of `h1` to place on the top of `border-line` of `div`. Now give some `width` and `margin-left` and `margin-right` as `auto`, this will center the heading.

See the fiddle: "http://jsfiddle.net/kboutd9q/1/"

See the screenshot as:

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this-

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
            
div {
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
}

h3 {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    height: auto;
    left: 20px;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div>
     <h3>Test</h3>
</div>
```